# Design suggestion for REST PUT without body data

Tags: api, rest

I'm designing a REST API that needs to create a database entry with only two columns, which together is the key. Because the ID is known in advance, I like to use PUT, like

PUT /lists/black/1.1.1.1

to black-list an IP. To remove it, I use

DELETE /lists/black/1.1.1.1

The problem is, many web servers doesn't allow PUT without a body (additional data arguments), and CURL doesn't send content-length: 0 by default, when doing a PUT request without arguments.

How do you suggest I design such an API?

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a REST API with a PUT without any content. It works fine. This is on Apache Tomcat v7

For cURL, use the header option `-H "Content-Length: 0"`

Answer (score 0):

you can do following for sending put without a body:

```
this.httpClient.put<string>(`url/user/reset-password/${password}`, {});
```